# Laravel - HasMany CRUD - Update

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I need some help, please,

I have two tables: **carriers** and **sell**

[image: Image of Yaktocat]

[image: Image of Yaktocat]

Carrier CRUD is working. Sell CRUD is also working, except **Update** method.

In order to update, i need **carrierId** and **sell id**, right?

This is my CarrierSellController:

[image: Image of Yaktocat]

And this is my **carriers/sell/edit.blade.php**

[image: Image of Yaktocat]

The model binding is working:

[image: Image of Yaktocat]

Form action has **/edit** at the end of the url. It's oke?

[image: Image of Yaktocat]

If i hit submit button, i get this error:

[image: Image of Yaktocat]

Comment: Because Route of /carriers/{carrierID}/sell/{id}/edit not declare.

Comment: And I recommend you must using ->where('id', '[0-9]+');

Comment: And on this picture you just update: I see method is GET. Please change to POST.

Comment: "Because Route of /carriers/{carrierID}/sell/{id}/edit not declare". Hello, Quynh, Am using ::resources() wich generates me the folowing route: /carriers/{carrierId}/sell/{sell}/edit. Should i declare one more time the same route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
{!! Form::model($sell,['url'=>url('carriers/'.$sell->carrier->id.'/sell/'.$sell->id),'method'=>'patch']) !!}
```

and in the Sell model add

```
public function carrier()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Carrier::class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure the method is `PUT`

add this to your form

```
{{ method_field('put') }}
```

Comment: Hi, Sherif, Thank your for your answer. http://oi68.tinypic.com/2ypcig5.jpg. After hitting update button, i get this error: MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you if you want to be absolutely sure just try declaring the route yourself like:

```
Route::put('carriers/{carrierId}/sell/{id}', [ 'as' => 'carriers.sell.update', 'uses' => 'CarrierSellController@update' ]);
```

And then in your view have this:

```
{!! Form::model($sell, ['method' => 'PUT', 'route' => ['carriers.sell.update', 'carrierId' => $sell->carrier->id, 'id' => $sell->id]) !!}
```